# cocos2dx error: opengl version too old

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I've upgraded my windows from 7 to 8 and I've started to compile cocos2dx but there is an error while the cmd is opening :

```
Your OpenGl Version is 1.1.0, but Cocos2d-x requires OpenGl 1.5 or higher on Windows. Please upgrade the driver of your video card
```

But cocos2dx was running well before upgrade!
could u tell me what is the problem and what should I do?
I'm using visual studio 2010.

Comment: Did you try upgrading the driver of your video card?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can see the cocos2d-x forum about this problem. watch this [link](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/boards/6/topics/18315).
your driver is not updated or you didn't install opengl. you can use older versions of cocos2d-x too. see this [link](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/boards/6/topics/18984).

Comment: Thank you so much! It works! But first we should check the version of video card from device manager, then download drivers of that.

Answer (score 0):

You should update your graphic card (video driver) drivers  or second way you try to run old version of cocos 2dx . i am also suffered this problem